# adjust x scale values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram, axis-labels

So I'm making a histogram of the months, but the x-axis goes from 0.5 to 12.5. Does anyone know how I can fix this to 1 - 12 (as they represent the months?

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)


qplot(x,geom='histogram',fill=I("red"), col=I("darkred"),xlab="Maand",ylab="Hoeveelheid",bins=12)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass x `as.factor`.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
x <- as.data.frame(x)

ggplot(x, aes(as.factor(x))) +
    geom_bar(fill = "red", color = "darkred") +
    xlab("Maand") +
    ylab("Hoeveelheid")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x)) + 
   geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, color="white") + 
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)
```

[image]

In base R you can try

```
hist(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))
```